# How can I use @around spring aop annotation on method declaration?

Tags: java, spring-boot, methods, spring-aop, spring-annotations

How can I use @around spring AOP annotation on method declaration? actually there are lots of duplicate code in the java class so I am thinking to optimize it.Only the @around execution values are getting changed every time  and method definition is same for 3-4 methods.Can you please suggest what I can do in this case for code optimization?Here in the given example you can see nicdStatus and nicdPortStatus are only getting changed and rest all the method definition is same.
            Please provide some suggestion for code optimization because I have duplicate code in my java class.

```java
@Around("execution(* dcp.casa.services.nicd.NicdController.**nicdStatus**(..)) && args(*, relationId,..)")
Object handleRunTest(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, final String relationId) {
    log.info("xyz");
    callAbc();
    return joinPoint.proceed();
}

@Around("execution(* dcp.casa.services.nicd.NicdController.nicdPortStatus(..)) && args(*, relationId,..)")
Object handleRunTest(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, final String relationId) {
    log.info("xyz");
    callAbc();
    return joinPoint.proceed();
}
```

Comment: Method declaration?

Comment: yes can I use it on method declaration ? like @Around("execution(* dcp.casa.services.nicd.NicdController.nicdStatus(..)) && args(*, relationId,..)")
    Object handleRunTest(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint,
    final String relationId);or do you have any idea how can I optimize the above code?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question is a bit unclear. Am I guessing right that you have multiple `@Around` advice methods with identical method bodies and you want to factor out those method bodies into a helper method in order to avoid code duplication within your aspect(s)?

Comment: yes you are correct @Kriegaex. you understood my question.

Answer (score 1):

AOP means you want to intercept some logic. While with @around , you are ready to put the some logic before and after some your method. That's good way to remove duplicate code.

What you need to do:

1) find all the methods with duplicate code.

2) abstract those duplicate code into some methods.

3) config with right pointcut.

[here](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-aop/aspectj-around-annotation-example/) have more example. Hope can help.

Answer (score 1):

> > Your question is a bit unclear. Am I guessing right that you have multiple `@Around` advice methods with identical method bodies and you want to factor out those method bodies into a helper method in order to avoid code duplication within your aspect(s)?
>
> yes you are correct @kriegaex. you understood my question.

Well, then the answer is simple: Just refactor like you would refactor any other Java class:

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingAspect.class);

  private void callAbc() {}

  @Around("execution(* dcp.casa.services.nicd.NicdController.**nicdStatus**(..)) && args(*, relationId, ..)")
  public Object handleRunTestA(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, String relationId) throws Throwable {
    return handleRunHelper(joinPoint);
  }

  @Around("execution(* dcp.casa.services.nicd.NicdController.nicdPortStatus(..)) && args(*, relationId, ..)")
  public Object handleRunTestB(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, String relationId) throws Throwable {
    return handleRunHelper(joinPoint);
  }

  private Object handleRunHelper(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    log.info("xyz");
    callAbc();
    return joinPoint.proceed();
  }
}
```

If the helper method also needs access to `String relationId`, just add another parameter to it and call it correspondingly.